# Stub a controller helper method in a template helper spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stub

My `ApplicationController` exposes a method (e.g. `sort_direction`) to the view templates by using `helper_method :sort_direction`. I then use this method in another method (e.g. `sort_link`) of a view helper (`application_helper.rb`).

When testing the `sort_link` method with RSpec (in `application_helper_spec.rb`) I have to stub `sort_direction` as the test seems to run complete independent from the controllers (and thereby by its to the view templates exposed methods).

Unfortunately I could not find out how to stub that `sort_direction` method of the controller. I always get "undefined method".

Here is what I tried so far (inside `application_helper_spec.rb`):

```
helper.stub(:sort_direction)
controller.stub(:sort_direction)
view.stub(:sort_direction)
self.stub(:sort_direction)
```

Any suggestions how I can stub that method?

Here the error I get:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `sort_direction' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0xb641434c>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

David Chelimsky solved that problem here: http://groups.google.com/group/rspec/browse_thread/thread/cc44ca12c6816053

Simply call in the spec all methods on the helper object:

```
it "should work" do
   helper.stub(:sort_direction)
   helper.sort_link(...).should == ...
end
```

Comment: This is now updated with rspec 3: `allow(helper).to receive(:sort_direction)` http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-1/docs/basics/allowing-messages