# Help stubbing out objects for my helper method test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My application_controller has a method

```
def current_user
end
```

This will return a User object.

Now using rspec, I am testing a helper in application_helper.rb

```
def test_this_method(some_object)

    ..
    ..  = some_other_method( current_user )

end


def some_other_method
  ..
  user.age
  user.height 
end
```

So I want to test `test_this_method` in the `application_helper`.

B**ut since it calls some_other_method, this has to be stubbed/mocked.  And also the current_user object has to be mocked as it is referenced also.**

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

This should be straight forward.

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'

describe ApplicationHelper do
  describe "test_this_method" do
    describe "when test_this_method do foo bar" do
      it "should show nothing" do
        helper.stub(:some_other_method)
        helper.test_this_method.should == ""
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Does this helps you?

Related answer can be. [Stub a controller helper method in a template helper spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373724/stub-a-controller-helper-method-in-a-template-helper-spec)